# Open ID 2.0 and Open ID Connect

Tags: openid, openid-connect

We are a Relying Party which currently uses OAuth 1.0.  We're looking to develop endpoints for OpenID and OpenID Connect.  My question is: If we develop a single endpoint for OpenID Connect, will it be compatible with OpenID, or the other way around?

The reason we need both is because we have Identity Providers that use each of these.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

No, OpenID Connect is not backwards compatible with OpenID 2.0. In fact OpenID 2.0 is deprecated.

Comment: Thanks.  I understand that openid 2.0 is deprecated but it's still being used by some of our partners, so we will have to support it.  I was hoping to only have to build out openid connect.  But from what you are saying it sounds like we will need to build out both.